# Using SSD as Read Cache in SQL Server having SAN as storage

Tags: sql-server

We are deploying SQL Server 2012 Ent. Ed. on WSFC cluster using a DELL SAN as storage.
SAN comes with 24TB of SAS disks (expandable) & 1.6 TB of SSD. We want to use this SSD as DB Read Cache.

While creating SSD read cache, the I/O characteristic type value has to be specified which, includes three options:
1. File System
2. Database
3. Web Server

Wanted to know which I/O option is to be selected for our use-case and what are the implications to keep in mind for it?

Kindly help with your valuable feedback.

Comment: Have you thought about deploying SQL Server 2014? There is a new feature called buffer pool extension which is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, we are aware about it, but we have already purchased SQL Server 2012 Ent. Ed.

Comment: How are you planning to use SSD as read cache without BPE?

Comment: Please refer below link which will clarify your doubt:- http://ukdl.synology.com/ftp/Document/WhitePaper/Synology_SSD_Cache_White_Paper.pdf

Comment: What is the function of your database, OLAP or OLTP?  That will dictate the I/O pattern which will drive which option you choose.  The documentation from dell should tell you what these 3 options mean, but I imagine the Web server expects 95% or more reads, the database is probably closer to 50/50 read/write, and the file system might be 80/20 read/write.  The wrong config will mean the cache is not optimally configured. It is unlikely to be a serious issue since this is a cache, it just won't perform as well as it could and you'd be wasting some of your precious SSDs.

Comment: Function of my database is OLTP.